# isolate/identify encapsulated parts of a string c# (identifying substrings)

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring

I have a text file from natural language filled with encapsulated data in the form of different tags. For example:

> ```
> <Age>53 year old</Age> woman, well known since earlier. Currently under the care of
> <First_Name>Sara</First_Name> <Last_Name>Storm</Last_Name> 
> and dr. <First_Name>John</First_Name> <Last_Name>Beck</Last_Name>
> ```

What would be the best way to extract all the tags and their data? The output I want is

> ```
>  <Age>53 year old</Age>
>  <First_Name>Sara</First_Name>
>  <First_Name>John</First_Name>
>  <Last_Name>Storm</Last_Name>
>  <Last_Name>Beck</Last_Name>
> ```

I have tried using a loop that iterates through the string to find the index of a tag. Since I want to add the different tags and capsuled data to lists this solution is not appropriate:

```
string findFirstName = "<First_Name>";
string findLastName = "<Last_Name>";
string endFirstName = "</First_Name>";
string endLastName = "</Last_Name>";
string findAge = "<Age>";
string endAge = "</Age>";

int startIndex;
int endIndex;
int length;
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(pieceContent, findFirstName))
{      
    startIndex = m.Index;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: why don't you use an XML parser for this?

Comment: @SelmanGenç - It is not XML.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Regex backreference to capture the tags:

```
var tags = Regex.Matches(input, @"<([_a-zA-Z]+)>.*<\/\1>");
```

The first capture group `([_a-zA-Z]+)` will match the tag name (there are more restrictions on XML names than this, but this is a simple example that just allows letters and underscores) - and the backreference `\1` matches the closing tag to the first capture group.

Comment: I must say, this backreference thing is extremely cool. Never heard of it before!